# cognos impromptu macro for prompt date entry

Tags: excel, vba

If I type in a file name to load an *.imr file after my Impromptu catalog is loaded, we have a prompt for a date to be entered. I get a syntax error by doing this way.

```
Strfilename = ("g:\ filename.imr", "10/15/2014")
```

The syntax error is generated from Impromptu.

I want to be able to put in the date automatically rather than having to type it.

Comment: Did you try Googling "VBA Date" ?

Comment: I've automated Cognos Impromptu via VBA and I'm having a difficult time understanding your question. Is the date part of the .imr file name? Because I don't get that. Or, is the date a prompt value you wish to send to the .imr when running it? Also, who's still using Cognos Impromptu???

Answer (score 0):

I haven't programmed Impromptu in over a decade, but I hope this can help you!

```
Sub passer()

Dim impapp As Object, imprep As Object, cutdate As Variant
On Error GoTo handler

Set impapp = CreateObject("impromptu.application.30")

cutdate = InputBox("Enter date: ")

impapp.Visible 1
impapp.opencatalog "d:\cognos\i66\samples\outdoors.cat", "Creator", "", "", ""
impapp.openreport "d:\cognos\i66\samples\reports\matt.imr", (cutdate)
Set imprep = impapp.activedocument
imprep.exportexcel ("d:\mydocu~1\matt2.xls")
imprep.closereport

Set imprep = Nothing
Set impapp = Nothing
Exit Sub

handler:
MsgBox "Error with " & Error$()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The date is a input into a [ prompt ] for the monday for that week. So I load the catalog and the .imr file,,,,,, then you have a prompt that asked for that monday,,, I can generate the Mondays date , and it doesn't matter weather I quote the "date" or value the date I get errors trying to add it to the end of the file name . Just like the way you did it there by adding  [  .imr", (date)  ]
that doesn't work eather.